# Error Creating Sequence In PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sequence

I have following PostgreSQL  create script

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_tbl_ct_yr2_id  START (select max(ct_tran_id)+1 tranid from tbl_ct);
```

this doestnt create sequence arising folloeing error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "(" LINE 1: create sequence test_1
>   start (select 1)

for test purpose i tested following scripts

```
create sequence test start 1 -- this works

create sequence test_1 start (select 1) -- this doesnt work
```

how to overcome this ??

Note : `PostgreSQL 9.2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DO
$$
declare
start_id int;
begin
select max(ct_tran_id)+1 from tbl_ct  into start_id;
execute 'CREATE SEQUENCE seq_tbl_ct_yr2_id  START '||start_id||'';
end;
$$
```

test using

```
select nextval('seq_tbl_ct_yr2_id')
```

[**sql-do**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-do.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can't specify the start value as a sub-select. However you can set the sequence to a specific value using `setval()`

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_tbl_ct_yr2_id;
select setval('seq_tbl_ct_yr2_id', (select max(ct_tran_id)+1 tranid from  tbl_ct));
```